Un error de un programa que ingresa un numero entero y muestra cada uno de sus digitos por separados
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int devolverCantCifras(int N){

int divisor = 1;

int cant_cifras = 0;

while(N/divisor >= 1){
    N=N/divisor;
    divisor=10;
    cant_cifras = cant_cifras+1;
}
return cant_cifras;
}

void mostrarNumSeparados(int n){
int cantidad_cifras = devolverCantCifras(n);
int i;
int valor_posicional = 1;
int numero_separado;
int valor_anterior = 0;

for(int x=0;x<cantidad_cifras-1;x++){
    valor_posicional=valor_posicional*10;
}
for(int x=0;x<cantidad_cifras;x++){
    numero_separado = (n - (n%valor_posicional) - valor_anterior) /valor_posicional);
    valor_anterior = n-( n%valor_posicional);
    valor_posicional = valor_posicional/10;
    cout<<numero_separado<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
   int numero;
   int cant_cifras = 0;
   cout<<"INGRESAR NUMERO: "<<endl;
   cin>>numero;
   cant_cifras = devolverCantCifras(numero);
   cout<<cant_cifras<<endl;
   system("pause");
   mostrarNumSeparados(numero);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

Buenas, este programa lo que hace es solicitar un numero y mostrar la cantidad de cifras y cada cifra por separado del numero, pero hay un error: A la hora de ingresar un numero con una cantidad de cifras mayor a 10 me muestra números que no ingrese ¿A que se debe esto? Muchas gracias :)
